# Android Studio: Populating list view with data from firebase realtime db

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, android-listview

I am trying to populate a list view with data from the firebase db. I have been sucessful in pulling the information and populating the list view but I am trying to enable item click listener for each item in the list and when a users name is selected, an alert diaglogue box will be display additional information about them from the database.

Database Schema can be seen below:

[image]

Code:

```
databaseReference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Customers");
        listView = root.findViewById(R.id.listView);
        arrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<>(getActivity(),android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,arrayList);
        listView.setAdapter(arrayAdapter);


databaseReference.addChildEventListener(new ChildEventListener()
        {
            @Override
            public void onChildAdded(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, @Nullable String s)
            {
                //String string = dataSnapshot.getValue(String.class);
                final String firstName = dataSnapshot.child("firstName").getValue().toString();
                final String surname = dataSnapshot.child("surname").getValue().toString();
                final String dob = dataSnapshot.child("dob").getValue().toString();
                final String contactNumber = dataSnapshot.child("contactNumber").getValue().toString();
                final String email = dataSnapshot.child("email").getValue().toString();

                arrayList.add(firstName + " " + surname);
                arrayAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

                listView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener()
                {
                    @Override
                    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id)
                    {
                        StringBuffer buffer = new StringBuffer();

                            buffer.append("First Name: " + firstName + "\n");
                            buffer.append("Surname: " + surname + "\n");
                            buffer.append("Date of Birth: " + dob + "\n");
                            buffer.append("Contact Number: " + contactNumber + "\n");
                            buffer.append("Email: " + email + "\n");
                            showMessage(firstName + " " + surname, buffer.toString());
                        }


                });



            }

public void showMessage(String Title,String Message)
    {
        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity());
        builder.setCancelable(true);
        builder.setTitle(Title);
        builder.setMessage(Message);
        builder.show();
    }
```

The app successfully displays the users name's from the db in a list view but when selecting the users name, the incorrect users information is displayed. In the second image, the first name from the list is selected.

[image]

[image]

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: I don't remember the correct syntax but you should call like this; final String firstName = dataSnapshot.position(position).child("firstName").getValue().toString();

Comment: What do you mean through "incorrect users information is displayed"? What is incorrect?

Comment: When I select the users name " Alice Jones", Joan Smith's information is displayed instead of Alice's.